# Outlook interop MailItem with F#

Tags: f#, outlook, vsto, c#-to-f#

I am converting C# to F# for outlook email messages. This function will be called inside a try...with block if an exception occurs to email me. I normally use an SMTP mail service that works in the production environment only. I have to use Outlook in Dev.

```
open System.Net.Mail
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Reflection
open System.Collections
open System.Threading
open Microsoft.Office.Interop
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

let sendEmail2 (sMessage:string) =
    let subject = "Load Failed at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "."
    let body = sMessage
    let app = new Outlook.ApplicationClass
    let mailItem = new app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)
    //let mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)
    mailItem.Subject = subject
    mailItem.Body = body
    mailItem.To = "user@mycompany.com"
    mailItem.Send()
```

The issue is creating the MailItem. The original C# code did this

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

I tried to use the C# code to the right of the equals sign, fully referencing the the interop assembly, etc. I even looked at an example from MSDN Word and Excel to reference the ApplicationClass. I even thought to use MailItemClass but, it is protected.

It always errors at the mailItem line with an error:

> Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression

Comment: Usually value assignment in F# looks like this `foo.bar <- value`.

Comment: Why do you have to use Outlook in dev? Have you looked at something like [smtp4dev](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: My company has firewalls that prevent me from using SMTP services in certain zones. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that there is a syntax error somewhere near the point where the error was reported. So, looking just at that, the first problem is that you are missing arguments when constructing an instance of `Outlook.ApplicationClass`. It should be:

```
let app = new Outlook.ApplicationClass()
```

As already mentioned in the comments, there are other issues - assignment should be written using `<-` and `app.CreateItem` is a method call, so you do not need `new` there:

```
let mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)
mailItem.Subject <- subject
mailItem.Body <- body
mailItem.To <- "user@mycompany.com"
```

As a side-note, this is probably not an area where you'd get a lot of benefits from using F#, so if this is for work, it might be better to leave the code in C# and use F# for some more functional problems than for Office interop. But you can certainly do this in F# too.

Comment: Thanks Tomas!!. The program is an executable for downloading log files and inserting the data into SQL server. Seemed like a good use of type providers and it's very fast. I just needed a way to get notified when the process fails since it is unmonitored, has no forms, and runs every hour. Thanks for fixing up the code for me.

Comment: @RT1138 Glad I could help! Yes, the data processing part seems like a great fit for F# :-) In that case, it's certainly worth the little bit of trouble with calling Outlook!